# Some magento functions are not working in outside magento(ajax page)

Tags: magento

I am trying to use ajax to place the product list from particular attribute(manufacturer).

In my ajax page i try to use

```
$this->__('hi'); //not working
```

error

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/shared/nftn/NFTN/js/ajax/ajax_designer.php on line 24

```
mage:__('hi'); //not working
```

error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::__() in /home/shared/nftn/NFTN/js/ajax/ajax_designer.php on line 23

i add required files in the top of the page

```
require "../../app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
```

Even these functions also not working

```
Mage::stripTags()

Mage::getLayout()
```

What was the problem.How can i make it work

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously `$this` has no meaning because you're not using it from within an object. All helpers have those functions, here I use `'core'` because it is the most generic but if you're writing for your own module then use your module's helper - it helps with translation.

```
Mage::helper('core')->__('hello');
Mage::helper('core')->stripTags('world');
```

`getLayout()` cannot work from an external file because there is no router/controller/action associated with the page, hence no layout to use.

---

The longer but slightly more correct way would be to work with Magento's controllers rather than external files. Say your module is `My_Module` and the AJAX URL is `www.example.com/mymodule/ajax/`...

**app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Module</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/My/Module/controllers/AjaxController.php**

```
<?php

class My_Module_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->__('hi'));
    }
}
```

For a more complex example see `Mage_CatalogSearch_AjaxController` in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/AjaxController.php`, it uses blocks as it's output which better follows the MVC paradigm.

Comment: :Thanks **Mage::helper('core')-> ** this works fine.But i unable to understand how to use getLayout().Please help me with explantion how to make it work.

Comment: I don't think `getLayout()` can be used in an external file, at least, I don't know of a way.